# How do I use the "with" symbol (|) in my own personal functions?

Tags: calculator, with-statement, texas-instruments, ti-basic, ti-nspire

I am a year 12 Maths student and recently I tried making a program that produces the function maximums and miniumums of any function. This is for my TI-nspire CX II. However, I am unaware of how to properly use the with '|' statement for my program.

My hacky solution is to have the constraint be part of the function, like so...
`fAbs(2-8*x^(2),−3≤x≤3)`

However, this makes it difficult when there are no restraints necessary for the function. As such, I would prefer a cleaner version that is used in all the default CAS functions, that being the with '|' statement. Idealy, the above function would instead look like so...
`fAbs(2-8*x^(2))|−3≤x≤3`

Does anybody know how to do this?